# SSL sniff VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, ssl, sniffing

I'm trying to sniff ssl traffic from a VirtualBox I created (Android). I'm using the build-in pcap system of VirtualBox to sniff regular traffic, but obviously that doesn't work for ssl. What I'm trying to do is generate new root keys and see what apps are vulnerable to this kind of attack (so actually it's a kind of MITM attack). But because there is no 'VirtualBox network interface', I'm kind of stuck here.
Is there someone who wants to give me a head start?

Answer (score 1):

SSL encryption is done at the application layer, so you would either need to modify the application you want to sniff (e.g. the browser) or you need to mount a man-in-the-middle attack (like with mitmproxy or burp suite). Passive SSL sniffing and decryption is only possible if you have the private key of the target server and if RSA key exchange is used, but modern sites use (EC)DHE key exchange which is resistent against this kind of sniffing.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a virtual network (`internet <--> proxy vm <--> (virtual) internal network`) and run a transparent intercepting proxy on the Gateway machine.
Here's a tutorial for mitmproxy: http://mitmproxy.org/doc/tutorials/transparent-dhcp.html

Comment: We here at Superuser expect more than a link to a third-party website in answers.

Comment: Updated, sorry.